# Erro ao tentar inserir dados no banco de dados Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, web-service

Estou tentando inserir dados de uma promoção no banco de dados *MySQL* através de um *Web Service REST* em *Java*, mas ao tentar inserir me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Grave:   ERRO ao Inserir Promocao - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mercado_db`.`promocao`, CONSTRAINT `id_produto_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_produto_fk`) REFERENCES `produto` (`idproduto`))
```

Método *adicionar*

```
public void adiciona(Promocao promocao) {

        id_conexao = N.Conectar();

        String sql = "insert into promocao (descricao, data_inicio, data_termino, id_produto_fk) values (?,?,?,?)";

        try {

            //PreparedStatement para inserção
            stmt = id_conexao.prepareStatement(sql);

            //setar valores
            stmt.setString(1, promocao.getDescricao());
            stmt.setString(2, promocao.getData_inicio());
            stmt.setString(3, promocao.getData_termino());
            stmt.setInt(4, promocao.getIdprodutoFk());

            //executa
            stmt.execute();
            System.out.println("Promoção Salva");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("ERRO ao Inserir Promocao - " + e);
        } finally {
            N.Desconectar();
        }

    }
```

Método *POST* para inserir via *Web Service*

```
@POST 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("inserirPromocao")
public void inserir(String content) {

    Gson g = new Gson();
    Promocao P = (Promocao) g.fromJson(content, Promocao.class);

    PromocaoOp promo = new PromocaoOp();
    promo.adiciona(P);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

de acordo com o mesmo erro exposto em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063652/integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row, o valor da coluna `promocao.id_produto_fk` que você tá inserindo não existe na tabela `produto`, aí viola a restrição de integridade referencial...

Ou seja, essa tabela `promocao` depende da tabela `produto`.